# Transaction input bigger than output

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

Yesterday I made a transaction from my one btc address to another by using pybitcointools library for blockchain api. I made a mistake by making input value 10x times higher than output value.
So I have a quesiton: Is that input minus output value treated as fee now, or can I restore it back in some way ?

Here is link transaction history ( only 1 transaction ) where you can see what's going on : https://blockchain.info/address/1Fno6XBjLbEq53oTG6MWw1X1vA2hbyaLPh?format=json

and here is transaction's blockchain link:
https://blockchain.info/tx/d80feae624c18067044e1bca0917bdb0c42f81ff1e7b9b2febacfced1ed7f691

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the difference between the input and the output is the transaction fee, and there's no way for you to get it back once it has been mined (except for building a fork that results in a stronger chain---not likely unless you have >50% of network hash rate).

In the future, I highly recommend experimenting on testnet (`bitcoind -testnet`) or using [regtest mode](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode).  That way you don't lose any wealth when you make a mistake.

Comment: I *believe* some people have had their excessive txn fees refunded my mining pools on rare occasions